# After Upgrade magento 2.1.13 to 2.3.3 getting error :SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint to system tables

Tags: mysql, magento, magento2

After Upgrade 2.1.13 To 2.3.3 when i am runnung php bin/magento setup:upgrade it give bellow error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'lifestylestoreco_magento/LSM2_EAV_ATTR_ENTT_TYPE_ID_LSM2_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID' to system tables, query was: ALTER TABLE `lsm2_eav_attribute` MODIFY COLUMN `attribute_model` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT "Attribute Model", MODIFY COLUMN `backend_model` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Backend Model", MODIFY COLUMN `backend_type` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT "static" COMMENT "Backend Type", MODIFY COLUMN `backend_table` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Backend Table", MODIFY COLUMN `frontend_model` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Frontend Model", MODIFY COLUMN `frontend_input` varchar(50) NULL  COMMENT "Frontend Input", MODIFY COLUMN `frontend_label` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Frontend Label", MODIFY COLUMN `frontend_class` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Frontend Class", MODIFY COLUMN `source_model` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Source Model", MODIFY COLUMN `note` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Note", ADD CONSTRAINT `LSM2_EAV_ATTR_ENTT_TYPE_ID_LSM2_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `lsm2_eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE 
I tried most of the things which i found in stack overflow and github.
like -
1- [Magento 2 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690185/magento-2-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1823-failed-to-add-the-foreign-key-con)
2- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256764/after-upgrade-2-2-5-to-2-3-0-getting-errorcms-block-store-block-id-cms-block-bl
3- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Not-able-to-setup-upgrade-SQL-error/td-p/136609

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice to upgrade to 2.3 from 2.1 is :

STEP: 1 Upgrade Magento 2.1.7 to 2.2.5

STEP: 2 Upgrade Magento 2.2.5 to Latest Version

Let's give it a try to prevent risk as much as possible.